# Add outputs generated from an existing column as a new column to the table

Tags: mysql, sql

In a table called *dates*, I have a column named *current_date*, which contains a list of dates. I want to add a column called *a_week_later* to the table, and it should contain a list of dates that are 7 days after the dates in *current_date*.

I am able to display *a_week_later* by using the query

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(current_date, INTERVAL 7 DAY) AS a_week_later from dates;
```

However, these dates are not stored in the table as a new column. I wonder how to add these outputs as a new column called *a_week_later* to the table.

Here's an example of the desired table contents:

```
current_date    a_week_later
20200101    2020-01-08
20200102    2020-01-09
20200103    2020-01-10
20200104    2020-01-11
```

Comment: referring to your edit request, Data type DATE will work for Week_later. I have tested it in Mysql. So there is no need to change data type. And i have corrected the column name: week_date to week_later. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to store such easily derivable data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real need to add a new column to your table. You have a couple of options. If you are running MySQL 5.7.6 or later, you can add a generated column to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE dates
ADD COLUMN one_week_later DATE AS (`current_date` + INTERVAL 1 WEEK);
SELECT * FROM dates
```

If you are running an earlier version you can create a `VIEW`:

```
CREATE VIEW later
AS SELECT *, `current_date` + INTERVAL 1 WEEK AS one_week_later
FROM dates;
SELECT * FROM later
```

In both cases the output would be

```
current_date    one_week_later
2020-01-01      2020-01-08
2020-01-02      2020-01-09
2020-01-03      2020-01-10
2020-01-04      2020-01-11
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9724ed4b66323db27721e2f1abd899c9)

Note that naming a column `current_date` is a bad idea as it is also the name of a MySQL function. If you ever forget to include the backticks around the column name, your queries will not get errors but will almost certainly return the wrong result. For example, with my small demo running on February 1st, here is the output from two queries, one of which forgets to quote `current_date`:

```
SELECT *, `current_date` + INTERVAL 1 WEEK AS one_week_later
FROM dates
```

Output (as expected):

```
current_date    one_week_later
2020-01-01      2020-01-08  
2020-01-02      2020-01-09
2020-01-03      2020-01-10
2020-01-04      2020-01-11
```

Second query (`current_date` unquoted):

```
SELECT *, current_date + INTERVAL 1 WEEK AS one_week_later
FROM dates
```

Output (note `one_week_later` is always February 1 + 7 days):

```
current_date    one_week_later
2020-01-01      2020-02-08
2020-01-02      2020-02-08
2020-01-03      2020-02-08
2020-01-04      2020-02-08
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6d6e2eacbc4764d98b1a9a6a04a1afb8)

Comment: Can you demonstrate your closing hypothesis

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
alter table dates add column week_later date;
update dates set week_later=DATE_ADD(current_date, INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```